# Page showing INVALID REQUEST while loading web2py with nginx and uwsgi?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, web2py

## Here is my uwsgi conf

I keep getting stuck at this point, Logs showing no error don't know whats going on !

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/web2py/socket
chdir = /home/ama/web2py/web2py
virtualenv = /home/web2py/venv
mount = /=wsgihandler:application
processes = 10
master = true
harakiri = 60
reload-mercy = 8
cpu-affinity = #2
stats = /tmp/uwsgi_stats.socket
max-requests = 2000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
touch-reload = /home/ama/web2py/web2py/routes.py
cron = 0 0 -1 -1 -1 python /home/web2py/web2y/web2py.py -Q -S batuni -M -R 
scripts/sessions2trash.py -A -o
no-orphans = true
plugins = python3
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting, what does routes.py look like, and are you sure the requested application folder exists?

Comment: sorry for the late reply , well i have a registered domain which i am requesting the problem is it shows "WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='/') ready in 1 seconds" .@Anthony